# Require an Optimal solution for a 2d matrix containing time for running tasks

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a 2d matrix of m processors(columns) and n tasks(rows), the matrix is populated with the time each process takes to run on a processor, I need to find the optimal time of runnng these n tasks on m processors.

Comment: could you show us what you have done so far? have you tried brute force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described problem belongs to the category of **Parallel Machine Scheduling Problems**.
Also, since each task takes different time on different processors the problem is called **Uniform Machine Scheduling Problem**.

This kind of problems are strongly NP-hard, hence no polynomial-time algorithm is known. So, a brute force approach is really discouraged unless the matrix is very small because the complexity is similar to `O( n ^ m )`.

That being said, an optimal approach is probably feasible for not-so-big matrices by using Mixed-Integer Linear Programming (MILP) and solving it with the best linear solvers like Cplex or Gurobi (I hardly think open source solvers like LP-solve can handle problems beyond a certain size).

An example of MILP model appliable to this problem is described [here](http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/lectures/ss10/scheduling_data/sched10_4.pdf).

However, given their complexity, this kind of problems are usually solved using heuristics/meta-heuristics and so without being sure to reach the optimal solution. Anyway, a good greedy algorithm followed with a good local search to improve the greedy solution, can go very close to the optimum.

**EDIT :**

A possible brute-force approach is computing all the possible combinations of assignments TASK-PROCESSOR and then compute the makespan. [Here's an example in C/C++](http://pastebin.com/J5R5WD7H)

Comment: I have 3 processors which are fixed ( columns). the rows ( the number of tasks ) is 5. I also have a target value T, the total time in which or closest to solve this problem. The process can run parallel, If a process that takes 6ms is running on processor 1, and a process that takes 8ms is running on processor 3, 3 processes can run on processor 2 which take time < 8 ms, which is the highest time from the 3 processors. How would I handle this problem ?

Comment: Thanks alot, i read through the linked MILP model, then took a look at the code, I was just wondering if it could be solved with some dynamic programing technique ? 

thanks a lot again

Comment: @jadedgoth: dynamic programming is appliable on problems having optimal substructure, i.e. if you divide the original problem in subproblems and you resolve them to optimum you get the optimum also for the original problem. Unfortunately, I son't think this kind of problems have an optimal substructure...

Comment: Thank you for the help :)
the problem i was given was not very clear, i read up on it, and searched the internet of the process scheduling algorithms you directed me to, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the total linear time it will take to do all the processing (add up the duration of all tasks).
Now divide that by the number or processors, `m`.

This is your target average time. You want to find a combination of durations for each processor which add up to as close as possible to this number

The most basic approach will be:

```
avg = <the average from earlier>
list = <all jobs>
FOR i = 0 to m
    WHILE duration(processor[i]) < avg:
        processor[i].add(longest lasting job in `list` that will keep the time less than `avg`
```

This will leave a few jobs at the end, add the longest lasting job to the shortest processor time until there are no jobs left in the `list`

Comment: If I have the target value for the optimal time, say T, and I want to find the time less then or equal to T, would the same algorithm work ? 
can you comment on this problem being solved by the 0-1 knapsack algorithm ?

Thank you very much sir

Comment: i need a dynamic programming solution for this problem, basically a 2d matrix with 5 rows ( 5 tasks ) and 3 columns ( 3 processors ) I need the optimal time, of running all these 5 tasks on the 3 processors using some dynamic programming technique.